# SDL Experience Optimization with DXA 1.4 Issues and Questions

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.4, experience-optimization

I have Following questions related to SDL Experience Optimization 8 with DXA 1.4:

1. To enable any component to be appear on the site based on personalised experience created in targeting in CMS, I have to make following settings to be "True" in deployer service : please confirm that this is the desire settings?

   ```
   <AddComponentPresentationContent>true</AddComponentPresentationContent>
   ```
2. I have placeed undeployer module configuration in deployer service as below, still when I unpublish any component in CMS it is not removed from the fredhopper indexer service folder:

> C:\fredhopper\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\data\xml\processed\batch

Settings in deployer service configuration:

> Module Type="SmartTargetUndeploy"
>   Class="com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperUndeployModule

3. I have configure google analytics along with SDL optimization installation, But I am not sure how to test/validate this configuration with DXA 1.4. Do we have any sample example created for the same.
4. Do we have any sample example using Javascript/Jquery to call cartridge  that execute query to fredhopper.

Thanks
Piyush Jain

Comment: Regarding question 3: do you mean you want to use XO Experiments? That is: A/B testing using Google Analytics to track link traversal?

Comment: Regarding question 4: why do you want to execute Fredhopper queries in Javascript?  The DXA XO Module already takes care of running the Fredhopper query and incorporating the result in the Page Model.

Comment: Just a friendly note for next time: please try to stick to one question per post :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 1: this setting should not be needed; we have it set to `false` on our DXA Test Environments where XO works perfectly fine.

**UPDATE**

Regarding question 3: check the XO docs for how to setup XO Experiments. From a Web App perspective, Experiments are just Promotions which will randomly show different items. Furthermore, the DXA XO Module automatically takes care of rewriting links within Experiment content so they get tracked in Google Analytics.

Regarding question 4: wow! That is a rather advanced requirement! I doubt that you will find existing implementations that are doing this. You would have to communicate from the client directly to the XO Query Service (which is likely not allowed). Wouldn't it be possible to ensure that Pages with XO Promotions (or any other dynamic content for that matter) are not cached in the CDN?

Comment: Q3: Yes I want to test google Analytics tracking for A/B testing also  based on tracking data like goal completion I want to show some targeted content  on home page, Please provide a link where I can see some sample example that uses google analytics with SDL Optimization with DXA 1.4

Comment: Q4.  We have a CDN (Akamai) Which cache all the URLs,  So I want to trigger cartridge using Jquery, such that it will show targetted content to the end user even full page is cached to CDN.